# Contact Form 7 + Paypal Integration

Tags: wordpress, paypal, contact-form-7

I have two options "New and Renewal". 
If user select Renewal option and submit the data they will charge 35$,
and if select New option then they will charge 50$.

How can I integrate Paypal by using this option button from contact form.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For simplier method
 1. Go to Contact (CF7) page and edit your form
 2. At the bottom of the page, find "Additional Settings"
 3. Place this code

```
on_sent_ok: "location = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=[YOUR BUTTON ID HERE]';"
```

Comment: on_sent_ok is now deprecated: https://contactform7.com/2017/06/07/on-sent-ok-is-deprecated/

Answer (score 1):

You can add paypal to contact form 7 easily with following steps
1. On paypal Go to My Account >> My profile >> My Selling Tools option >> Update Link of Paypal Button
2. Create a new paypal button 
3. After that choose the contact form that you want to edit
4. Find Additional Settings at bottom of the contact form edit page
5. Add the below code after replacing paypal button id with the code you have copied from the paypal site

```
on_sent_ok: "location = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=[YOUR BUTTON ID HERE]';"
```

Source: http://www.mytechshout.com/add-paypal-contact-form-7-plugin/

Comment: would you really do this in production for your own website?